# My pen drive is not detected in boot menu for dual booting ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10 and RST disabling

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, rst

I have a dell 15 g3 3590 laptop with 9th gen i5 processor, 8GB of DDR4 RAM, and an SSD of 512GB. I have windows preinstalled in it and my bios mode is UEFI. I have also disabled fast startup and secure boot and also made an unallocated partition of 100000MB for Ubuntu I made a bootable disk using rufus tool but when I chose GPT in it and the Live USB was created but when i rebooted my PC, In the boot menu my Live USB was not showing , But when I chose MBR in it my disk was showing in it and when i clicked it two lines were shown as

```
    failed to create kernel channel, -22
    failed to parse event in tpm final event log
```

and then ran the disk check but after that it was stuck on dell logo for a long time when i repeated this process i was able to enter to the setup but after connecting to a network, In the next menu It shows a warning of RST and asked to restart when i restarted it directly booted to windows. Please HELP ! I want to dual boot my laptop.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware? And if SSD its firmware?  Dell typically needs UEFI update, if SSD also SSD firmware update.
It needs UEFI setting for drives changed to AHCI, not Intel RST nor RAID. But if dual booting with Windows you must first install AHCI drivers into Windows or it will not boot. Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized And possibly: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191031/installation-on-new-laptop-dell-inspiron-5491-freezes

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS settings and under General section click on Advance Boot Options and check Enable Lagacy Option ROMs.
Go to boot menu again. Your USB drive name will start with UEFI in boot menu. So look for it and hopefully you will find it there.