# I tried ubuntu 20.04 live usb and its not working. Which version of ubuntu will run in my laptop with persistence storage

Tags: live-usb, usb-installation

My processor is Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3710 @ 1.60GHz × 4 with 4GB RAM.
I tried ubuntu 20.04 but its not running. which version support this spec. which one is better for low specs laptops ubuntu, fedora or mint. I need persistence storage. I tried tail os but its tor browsing is slow, is there any way for normal internet connection in tail os

Comment: Does your computer support 64-bit os? What happened when you tried to boot 20.04? You can try the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04 (it will be supported until 2023).

Comment: @FedonKadifeli when i tried 20.04 it is stuck in a black screen and iam forced to reboot after waiting a long time. how can i check 64 bit os support

Comment: Ubuntu should run, but Lubuntu would be better. It is a 64 bit chip. What brand/model laptop. Some need settings. Is UEFI updated to latest available from vendor?

Comment: @oldfred brand is dell. i dont know about UEFI. I will try Lubuntu then

Comment: Dell typically needs UEFI update, if SSD also SSD firmware update.
It needs UEFI setting for drives changed to AHCI, not Intel RST nor RAID. But if dual booting with Windows you must first install AHCI drivers into Windows or it will not boot.
Often better to have UEFI Secure boot off. And UEFI fast boot off, as that assumes no system changes & you are changing system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191031/installation-on-new-laptop-dell-inspiron-5491-freezes