# Dual Booting Ubuntu 20.04 - RST / RAID / BitLocker

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, raid, rst

I have been trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my new Dell Precision 5540 laptop to no avail. It started with Intel RST issues which i handled following the steps detailed here https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Afterwards it changed to the BitLocker issue. I have checked with my windows installation that BitLocker is not even enabled yet the problem persist. I have turned Bitlocker on and off to no avail. Any way out of this issue?

Comment: Other Dell systems. Many issues common across models. How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191031/installation-on-new-laptop-dell-inspiron-5491-freezes

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a partition. You can do this by going to the disks application, and then go into the main hard drive and on file system lick the settings button and resize partition to what you want then you will get the 'free space' partition, then click settings button on that, mount the operating system and make sure the box 'bootable' is ticked.

But you will need GParted first, otherwise it is almost impossible to do this.

But this might cause problems, so make sure ALL of your files are backed up, because resizing might cause problems