# Duel boot error: You need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I've recently decided to add a HDD to my laptop and have Ubuntu boot of a partition of that drive. It is both for an alternative workspace but also a backup OS if my main nvme corrupts again. If your interested in parts, I'll add a list of my hardware below.

My first attempt at installing Ubuntu was successful. I could boot and shut down the computer fine. after 3 boots however, the computer would freeze before GRUB could load. When it did load, it would pull up errors and say 'You need to load the kernel first'. I then gave my Windows 10 boot priority and formatted the HDD to try it again.

My second attempt went the same with Ubuntu installing until the first restart was needed. From there GRUB loaded again but then began to give me the 'you need to load the kernel first' error straight away. Selecting windows to boot from the GRUB menu also brought up errors.
Please any advice would be useful, this is my first time trying to make a dual boot setup.
Hardware specifications and other information is underneath:

Computer model: Dell Inspiron 5593

Linux Info:

- Ubuntu Version 20.04.3
- 69GB boot partition on a 500GB HDD
- GRUB 2.04 BootLoader

List of hardware:

- Intel Core i5-1035G1 CPU
- 16GB 2666 MHz RAM
- Samsung m.2 nvme 980 500GB (Windows 10)
- WD5000LUCX HDD 500GB (Storage & Ubuntu)
- Qualcomm QCA9377 802. 11ac Wireless Adapter
- Intel(R) UHD Graphics

Added info:

Secure boot is off and I installed Ubuntu through a live usb in UEFI mode.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in the UEFI mode? See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) for pictures of booting the USB installation drive in UEFI and BIOS/Legacy modes. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1394051/edit) and add the new information.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Similar issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191031/installation-on-new-laptop-dell-inspiron-5491-freezes